# Comparison between IList and IList<object> - should any be preferred?

Tags: c#, generics

Since many years, we use generic collections most of the time. Sometimes we really do need a collection of anything (well, usually only a few different things but with no common base class). For such circumstances we can use either `IList` or the generic `IList<object>` as type for method arguments and properties.

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Performance characteristics?

Personally, I'm leaning towards `IList<object>`, as I think this makes it more clear that we really do accept "anything". When a parameter is typed as `IList` we cannot immediately tell if this method do accept anything, or if the lack of generics is due to history or sloppy coding.

Comment: `IList` is just for legacy code. Use `List<object>`

Comment: I say that the reason you identify -- that one more clearly communicates intent to the reader than the other -- is sufficient to prefer it. Reading code to determine intention is difficult, so make it easier on your future selves.

Comment: Using either `IList` or `IList<object>` would incur boxing for value types.  also, list implies ordering, if you don't need a particular order `HashSet` (IEnumerable / `IEnumerable<T>`) might be better.  `Hashset` has more a constant ( O(1) ) performance for finding values whereas `List` is more linear ( O(n) ).  If you're simply going to enumerate from "beginning" to "end", then `List` would likely be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a good reason: LINQ and its extension methods. These aren't implemented for pre-generics era types. **You will need to call `Cast<T>` on the `IList` to take advantage of LINQ!**

Other point is that, since newest .NET versions support covariance and contravariance and most of generic interfaces support one or the other (f.e. `IEnumerable<out T>`, `T` is covariant), you can easily downcast or upcast interfaces' generic parameters from and to object or a less-unspecific type.

Conclusion: why generics should be prefered?

- Generic types have better performance because they avoid a lot of casts.
- Newer APIs rely on generic collections and interfaces.
- There're a lot of reasons to think that mixing objects of different types in the same list could be dangerous and a bad coding/design decision. And for the few cases where you'll store any kind of object, having LINQ and many other newer APIs and features as your friend is a powerful reason to don't reinvent wheels and save a lot of time!

Comment: With `IList` that code would be exactly the same (because [`OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) works on the non-generic `IEnumerable`).